# Is there a way to embed YouTube vids with kivy?

Tags: python, video, kivy

is there a way I can embed videos in a python app using kivy?

I couldn’t find any module for that and not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy can stream videos from the internet and play them in VideoPlayer. However, YouTube does not provide a streaming URL. Remember that YouTube only gets paid when they show ads, which means they want you on their site and need you to use their video player.

I can think of two options:

Use a YouTube downloader app to retrieve the video (or, alternatively, try to hack on one of the downloaders and see if you can figure out what they're doing and how to duplicate it in Kivy).

Use the Chromium Embedded Framework to display an actual web page. I have no idea whether this will work with Flash or not, but in theory it would work for any HTML5 videos (but not all videos can be watched in HTML5). There is a CEFPython Garden widget available, as well as a non-Garden CEFKivy component which has more recent development.